# Trying to append an array of html elements to a div element on a page with jquery but it's not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to add an array of html element to a div element on a page but it's not showing. When I do a console.log on the div element it prints the array confirming that the array is added to the div element yet it doesn't appear on the page. below is the code for what I.m trying to do:

html:

```
<form action="question" method="post">
    <div class="combobox">
        <label for="switchQuestion">Switch Question:</label>
        <select id="switchQuestion"></select>
    </div>
    <div id="go-btn">
        <input id="go" type="button" value="Go" />
    </div>
</form>

<div class="exam-container">
    <div id="exam-question"></div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
const $examQuestions = $('#exam-question'),
output = [];

loadQuestions($examId, function(question){
    for(let i in question) {
        $switchQuestion.append($('<option />').val(question[i].id).text(Number(i)+1));
        loadChoices(question[i].id, question[i].multiAnswer, function(choices) {
            output.push(
                    `<div class='question'> ${(Number(i)+1)}. ${question[i].problemDescription} </div>
                     <div class='choices'> ${choices.join('')} </div>`
            );
        });
    }
});

output.join('');
$examQuestions.innerHTML = output;

function loadChoices(id, isMulti, callback) {
    let choices = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/online-test-exam-maker' +'/choices/' + id,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data, status) {
            let elemType = isMulti ? 'checkbox' : 'radio';
            $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                choices.push(
                    `<label>
                      <input type='${elemType}' name='${v.questionId}' value='${v.id}' id='${v.id}' />
                      ${v.choiceText}
                     </label>`
                );
            });
            if(typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(choices);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: $examQuestions.html(output)

Comment: @Pavlo sorry, that was a mistake I've corrected it.

Comment: Still wrong, `innerHTML` doesn't exist in jQuery, use `.html()` instead

Comment: i've tried     .html() and     .append() too but still not showing on the page. with these, the array is not added to the div element when I do console.log($examQuestions)

Comment: Sorry, can you show me $switchQuestion and loadChoices?

Comment: I've added $switchQuestion and loadChoices to the code.

Comment: Found the problem, if this doesn't work then i need to know how `loadQuestions()` is called. After `output.push()` you have to write `output.join(''); $examQuestions.html(choices);`

Comment: `output.join('');` occurs while `output` is still an empty array.

Comment: Just after output.push(), if i do $examQuestions.html(ouput.join(' ')), it works. Thank you for your help, Pavlo!

Comment: @Kevin B It's not a duplicate question, I've edited the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace everything in the div do:

```
$examQuestions.html(output)
```

else you can also use jQuery's `append` method like:

```
$examQuestions.append(output)
```